# ExpressJS error: MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

When launching my NodeJS server and typing `localhost:8080`, I get the previously mentioned error as it loads the page. Below is my head section in my `index.html` file, I'm not sure why this occurs, my `index.html` is in the same directory as `script.js` and `style.css`.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Express & Node Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Using the following snippet from my `app.js` file for ExpressJS routing.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/web/index.html"));
});
```

I've had no success searching my problem so I have resorted to asking on StackOverflow, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you sending other things like `style.css`?  Are you using the `static` express middleware?

Comment: @JoséRamírez Thanks for the help, I've solved the issue by serving files from my alternative directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your code like this in order to serve files from the current directory, Instead of path.join you can use:

```
      app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"); });
```